# jms on jboss: how to set delay time of message

Tags: jms

"The delay represents a time interval after which the message becomes available to the Message Consumer. A message specified with a delay is in a waiting state until the delay expires and the message becomes available"

how to set it on JBoss (5.1)? thanks

Comment: What was the quote referring to? Your message has very little context, please elaborate.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution:

```
for (int i = 1; i < num_of_your_message; i++) {
  message.setLongProperty("JMS_JBOSS_SCHEDULED_DELIVERY",
            (new Date()).getTime() + 5000 * i);
  message.setObject(your_object);
  producer.send(message);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be quoting a passage from the Oracle [AQ JMS manual](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/A87860_01/doc/appdev.817/a76938/adq12ja6.htm).  If you'd quoted a couple of more sentences, that would have been clear...

> Delay for a message is specified as
>   message property (JMS_OracleDelay).
>   This property is not specified in the
>   JMS standard. It is an AQ extension to
>   JMS message properties.

If JBoss 5.1 has a similar proprietary extension, read their docs on how to use it.  If not, you're out of luck.

BEA's (now Oracle's) WLS JMS has a similar feature (added in version 7?).  Maybe it's a popular thing for vendors to add.  Maybe you'll get lucky w/ JBoss...

Comment: yes, JBoss 5.1 has JMS_JBOSS_SCHEDULED_DELIVERY_PROP_NAME property, thank you